# CSS Attribute Selectors Exclude

Tags: css, web, frontend

I'm trying to get my icon font to work and I need to exclude `icon-blue`

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {

  font-family: 'fontname';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]
```

dont make sense because [class^="icon-"] is included in [class*=" icon-"]

To exclude you can use:

```
[class*="icon-"]:not(.icon-blue)
```

You have a full example to play here:
http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/dozjZW

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) selector like

```
[class^="icon-"]:not([class="icon-blue"]),
[class*="icon-"]:not([class="icon-blue"]) {

  font-family: 'fontname';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

```css
[class^="icon-"]:not([class="icon-blue"]),
[class*="icon-"]:not([class="icon-blue"]) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-red">test</div>
<div class="icon-yellow">test</div>
<div class="icon-blue">blue</div>
<div class="small-icon-red">test</div>
```

Note, you can simplify your selector to just

```
[class*="icon-"]:not([class="icon-blue"]) {
```

since `*=` will cover the `^=` cases also.

Comment: Looks like the `:not([class="icon-blue"])` takes over and `[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]` no longer works

Comment: @SteveJones, sorry, see my correct answer with an example

Comment: @SteveJones, does it still not work? Let me know so I can help

Comment: thank you but that still didn't work, this did: `[class*="icon-"]:not(.icon-blue)`